# redirect each command output to respective log file expect script

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, zsh, expect

```
set commands {
   "show phone xxx 11"
   "show phone yyy 22"
   "show phone zzz 33"
}

spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UserId@$host
sleep 15
#wait for password prompt
expect "*assword:"
#send password 
send -- "$Passwd\r"
sleep 5
foreach cmd $commands {
    set logfile [join [lrange [split $cmd] 2 end] _]
    log_file -a $logfile
    send -- "$cmd\r"
    expect -re "admin:"
    exp_sleep 8
    log_file
}
```

was not able redirect command's output to respective log file.

```
xxx_11 log file contains 'spawn ssh -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no $UserId@$host' output.
yyy_22 log file contains 'show phone xxx 11' command output.
zzz_33 log file contains 'show phone yyy 22' command output.
```

How to write log files in the following way:

```
XXX_11 log file contains 'show phone xxx 11' command output
yyy_22 log file contains 'show phone yyy 22' command output
zzz_33 log file contains 'show phone zzz 33' command output
```

Thanks in adavnce for help.

Comment: You have used both the [tag:bash] and [tag:zsh] tags. What are the relevance of these tags to your question?

Comment: If you have your patterns correct, you don't need `sleep`. If you find you need to `sleep`, your patterns are wrong, and you should use `expect -d script` to debug the patterns.

Answer (score 1):

The first `expect -re "admin:"` will read the output of `ssh` up to the first `admin:` prompt. Presumably such a prompt is issued *before* you start sending commands.

You're missing an `expect` call *before* your loop to *consume* all the output sent so far before you send your commands. If you don't know what output to *expect*, you could replace your `sleep 5` with an `expect` anything with timeout.

Comment: Thanks stephane, by adding expect call before loop solved my issue.